how to convert template to string?
I have a class XArrayList<T> that has a T *data; attribute, i need to make a
toString(string (*item2str)(T &)) function to convert the data to string follow this description
/**
     * Converts the array list into a string representation, formatting each element using a user-defined function.
     * If no function is provided, it uses the default string representation for each element.
     * Example: Given an array list with elements {1, 2, 3} and a function that converts integers to strings, calling toString would return "[1, 2, 3]".
     *
     * @param item2str A function pointer for converting items of type T to strings. If null, default to the string conversion of T.
     * @return A string representation of the array list with elements separated by commas and enclosed in square brackets.
     */

So as i understand, if the type is a normal type as int, double we will use to_string to convert the data to string and if the type is a pointer or a class we will use the item2str to convert data to string:
    string rtn = "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        rtn = rtn + ((item2str)?item2str(data[i]):to_string(data[i])) + ", ";
    }
    if (count > 0) {
        rtn = rtn.substr(0, rtn.length() - 2);
    }
    rtn += "]";
    return rtn;

but when i compile i get error
error: invalid conversion from 'Point*' to 'long long unsigned int' [-fpermissive]
  398 |         rtn = rtn + ((item2str)?item2str(data[i]):to_string(data[i])) + ", ";
      |                                                             ~~~~^
      |                                                                 |
      |                                                                 Point*

How should i do it?

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically please post a [mre].

"If no function is provided, it uses the default string representation for each element." This doesn't quite work. What if there is no default string representation for the element?

It seems that you have found the problem in your professors assignment. I think you are going to have to write a function to_string(Point* p) to implement the default string representation.

Incidentally why do you have a XArrayList<Point*>? You should not use pointers where they are not needed, XArrayList<Point> is much better. Then you would need to implement to_string(const Point& p) which also makes much more sense.

@HuyNhật Then you will have to ask your professor about that. It's normal when writing templates to say that any class used by this template must have certain things defined.

@John Is should be to_string(const Point& p) to avoid "misuse", eg. modifying the input variable or passing in a nullptr

You need to write a function to_string for every type that you instantiate XArrayList with.
It looks like you have using std::to_string; or equivalent in your program, which covers the arithmetic types. Any other types you will need to implement yourself.

So as i understand, if the type is a normal type as int, double we will use to_string to convert the data to string and if the type is a pointer or a class we will use the item2str to convert data to string

No. The requirement says you can pass a custom item2str for arithmetic types, or use the "default" for other types.

For what you are attempting to do, you would have to define a custom to_string() overloaded function for every non-native type that you store in your XArrayList.
However, it is customary for a user-defined class that is intended to be printed to provide an operator<< overload for itself.  That would fall more inline with your "default string representation" requirement (as operator<< is overloaded by default for more types than std::to_string() is). For example:
class Point {
public:
    ...
    friend std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Point &pt) {
        out << ...; // print pt members as needed...
        return out;
    }
};

In your case, I would suggest using a std::ostringstream to format the output, using operator<< instead of to_string() to print out each element, eg:
template<typename T>
std::string XArrayList<T>::toString(std::string (*item2str)(const T &)) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << '[';
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ) {
        if (item2str)
            oss << item2str(data[i]);
        else
            oss << data[i];
        if (++i < count)
            oss << ", ";
    }
    oss << ']';
    return oss.str();
}

That being said, do note that you are storing Point* pointers in your list.  The default behavior of operator<< for a pointer is to print the memory address that the pointer is pointing at.  If that is not what you want, then to convert a Point* pointer to a std::string the way you want, you would need to provide either a custom function for item2str() or an overload of operator<<, taking a Point* pointer as input (and preferably calling the Point class's own operator<<), eg:
std::string PointPtrToStr(Point* const &ptr) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << *ptr; // print ptr members as needed...
    return oss.str();
}

XArrayList<Point*> arr;
arr.toString(PointPtrToStr);

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, Point* const &ptr) {
    out << *ptr; // print ptr members as needed...
    return out;
}

XArrayList<Point*> arr;
arr.toString(nullptr);

If you change your array to hold actual Point objects, then simply drop the * everywhere:
std::string PointToStr(const Point &pt) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << pt; // print pt members as needed...
    return oss.str();
}

XArrayList<Point> arr;
arr.toString(PointToStr);

// no need for a separate operator<< here since Point already has one above...

XArrayList<Point> arr;
arr.toString(nullptr);

